# Is there any single word for this type of trap?

Tags: single-word-requests

On a Drama stage, They have numbers written below the floor. Man from bottom, see the numbers where Actor is standing (he can't see but hear where footsteps stops). so Man from below see that number where he stops and Pull that lever related to number, then actor will fall to bottom.

Example: https://youtu.be/01ZWXIY1mcs   (Thanks to @Clare)

Comment: Which movie is that in? Is it *Charade*?

Comment: Yeah it is https://youtu.be/01ZWXIY1mcs

Comment: @Clare I want single word for this type of trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic name for a door in a stage is *trap door.*

Comment: The answer is of course excellent but you might add a link to 'trap door' at a theatre related page such as this one https://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.theatrecrafts.com/pages/home/glossary-of-technical-theatre-terms/trap-doors-stage/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjn18G619PVAhUTSI8KHcD8BQwQFggNMAA&usg=AFQjCNE2VNAv6sBV6TLSZ7w4UhkddHr-7Q  or at least this more general wikipedia link https://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjn18G619PVAhUTSI8KHcD8BQwQFggZMAU&usg=AFQjCNF3xlO0H7rx9b2wDuwmQUnEOKewsg (article on trapdoors which specifically mentions theatre use)